# html code(with onclick()) written in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

Following code created table dynamically in separate java script file and each row has created button dynamically with onclick() function and also created link dynamically with calling some function when click on link but both not working means "onclick" not working.
I want to call another function when I click on button "Clear Login" which is wriiten in that JS file

```
if(reclist[8] == 'F')
{
    //alert(1);
    string[j] += "<td><input type='button' disabled='true'name='but_clrlgn_"+reclist[2]+"' value='Clear Login' id='but_clr_"+reclist[2]+"' onClick=\"ClrLogin(this.name)\"></input></td>";
}
else
{
    alert(reclist[8]+" "+reclist[2]);
    string[j] += "<td><input type='button' disabled='true' name='but_clrlgn_"+reclist[2]+"' value='Clear Login' id='but_clr_"+reclist[2]+"'  onClick=\"ClrLogin(this.name)\"></input></td>"; 
    string[j] += '<td><input type="button" value="Click" id="click"/> </td>';
    string[j] += "<td><a href='javascript:aaa()' id='location' >GPS Location</a></td>";
```

Comment: In both td tag of Clear Login button I removed disabled='true'. It is written by mistake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all change html like this

```
"<td><input type='button' name='but_clrlgn_"+reclist[2]+"' value='Clear Login' id='but_clr_"+reclist[2]+"' class=\"your_button_class\"></input></td>";
```

then use $(document).ready function and add onclick event in jquery .on function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".your_button_class",function()
    {
        //your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: No still it is not working .... It gives "The value of the property 'ClrLogin' is null or undefined, not a Function object" on IE 9

Comment: you need to remove call from html

Comment: Yes I removed call from HTML and I tried using class ,still not working

Comment: External JS:                                                                                            var var string = "<td><input type='button' name='but_clrlgn' value='Clear Login' class='logclr'  ></input></td>";

JSP Page which contains document.ready :
$(document).ready(function() 
{
 //alert(22);
 $(document).on("click",".logclr",function()
    {
        alert('Call success');
    });
});

Comment: and how the html generated in var string add in page html?

Comment: doc.open();
var div = doc.createElement("div"); 
   div.id="table1";
var str = "<table BORDER CELLPADDING=8 id='table'>";
   str =str+ "<tr>";
str += "</table>";
   alert(str);
   div.innerHTML = str;
   doc.body.appendChild(div);

Using this I add HTML code in Javascript

Comment: add this into external js not in page
document.ready : $(doc).ready(function() { //alert(22); $(doc).on("click",".logclr",function() { alert('Call success'); }); });

Comment: I create doc as :

var testFrame = document.getElementById("srcheng");
 var doc = testFrame.contentDocument;
   if (doc == undefined || doc == null)
    doc = testFrame.contentWindow.document;
    
   var val="";
   val += "<TABLE border=1>";
      val += "<script src=\"../js/ExamMonitoringD.js\"></script>";
   val += "<script src=\"../js/library.js\"></script>";
   doc.open();
   doc.write(val);

Comment: val += '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".your_button_class",function()
    {
        //your code here
    });
});</script>';

Comment: I am trying document.ready in JSP file but we are using different document object (ie doc) so as you giving me code ...it works on that doc object....Thanks again...

Comment: dont forget to accept and vote up the answer by clicking on tick and up arrow symbols. u welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want call to a different function my suggestion is remove the onclicks with something like this `.removeAttr("onclick");` and then do whatever you want using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourButton').on('click', function(){
        // your code
    });
});
```

Comment: No still not working and I tried this on IE 9 and It also not display any Error